# Go GC Doesn't seem to be collecting my unreferenced pointers for image loading?

Tags: image, go, garbage-collection

I'm working on a project in Go with OpenGL and have code to load an image file via the go/image library. This function leaves no permanent pointers and then I leave scope of the function. I would hope this memory gets cleared on the next GC cycle, but it does not appear to. I'm hoping someone who understands go a little better can help me see why the image isn't being cleared.

Gist of the code: https://gist.github.com/gjh33/62a75ccde6a7d849311804d31d7ee9ff

When not calling this method, memory footprint is 17mb, when calling this method it is 40mb. At no point is this memory GC'd even after waiting 5 minutes.

Some things to keep in mind if you haven't worked with openGL in go:

- The converstions to unsafe pointers(Line 41) happen via: https://github.com/go-gl/gl/blob/master/v3.2-core/gl/conversions.go
- I'm using go-gl v3.2-core
- If you need more information or context, just ask

Comment: usually I think `gc` clears only when heap memory is doubled, and if it's too high frequently, once try adding this `defer runtime.GC()` at the very beginning of your load func. This runs `gc` and clears everything.

Comment: How do you measure memory consumption? Note that just because the GC reclaims memory this does not necessarily mean that it's returned to the OS. The runtime keeps the memory around for a bit (more than five minutes is not unusual) in case it's needed for something else soon, so the GC's work cannot be accurately observed with OS tooling (use [runtime.ReadMemStats](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) instead).

Comment: @Peter This is probably the correct answer. I am in fact just using a simple task manager. I think I expected it to be free because I'm trying to Go as a language closer to the likes of C and C++ with low overhead and strong control, but more and more I'm seeing this may not be what Go is. Still an awesome language

Answer (score 3):

> when I leave scope of the function, I would hope this memory gets cleared

This is a chief misconception: Go is a garbage-collected language, and this means the memory is only freed during so-called garbage collections, which happen *periodically*
and are not in any way triggered by variables in the code being executed getting out of scope.

It suffices to say that in the GC algorithm Go implements, each scan consists of two consecutive phases: scanning and sweeping.
During the scan phase, all the live objects are traversed (via pointers they maintain to each other, if any, and those which are unreachable via the stacks of the running goroutines and global variables are marked for freeing which happens during the sweep phase.

The Go runtime implements a quite sophisticated "estimator" which tries to deduce at which *target heap size* to start the next GC session in order to strike a balance between the heap usage and the CPU cost paid for performing a GC session.

This means two things:

- In Go, the fact you lost all references to a chunk of allocated memory means nothing to the runtime: this fact will only be considered during the next GC cycle.
- In an idling program, which performs no allocations, a piece of allocated memory has a chance of not being collected at all—since no GC cycle will ever be performed.

---

On a side note, the original mental image of how a GC
works which you held is not untrue *per se*—there indeed exist programming languages with no explicit memory management which actually de-allocate the memory in cases like the one you have mentioned. This is typical for scripting (at least originally) programming languages such as Python, Tcl, Perl (≤ 5 at least) etc. These languages use so-called reference-counting for the *values* they operate with. The logic is basically that every assignment of a value to a variable (including passing it as a function's argument) increments a number of references recorded for that variable, and when the execution leaves the scope of a variable, the refcount of the value held in it is decremented. When a value's refcount drops to 0, the value is freed.

This approach works, and appears to be natural, but it has certain downsides such as:

- The need to maintain a refcount field for each value.
- The need to spend CPU cycles each time that field has to be updated (add to that also the CPU cache thrashing).
- Inability of this scheme to deal with cyclic references.

I would also add to this that this scheme does not play well with concurrent access to the variables: if you add concurrency (as in Go) in the mix, you'll end up with the requirement for all updates of these refcount fields to be mutually exclusive and with unfunny problems following such as how to deal with the case when one thread of execution unreferences a value, notices the refcount crossed the zero and frees the value and then another thread waiting on the former to increment the reference gets unblocked and finds out the value it wanted to reference does not exist any more.

Comment: @nilsocket, JFTR, they are "goroutines", not "go-routines". It may be grammatically incorrect to call them like this but this is how [the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) and any other resource on Go calls them. Thanks for the other suggested changes, though!

Comment: to add up on this answer, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n59VtiRx34s

Comment: I phrased that poorly. What I meant to say was not that the GC is collected when I exit scope. I do know that. I meant that the fact I have no external reference and it is out of scope would make me expect in the next GC sweep it will get marked for collection. However after waiting 10 minutes my memory footprint did not change. My program is running a loop that is just telling GL to render to the screen, so the program is active, and not referencing the memory I allocated. Therefore I don't understand why it's not being cleared during GC cycles

Comment: @gjh33, ah, you then may experience what @Peter explained: the GC keeps collected memory for itself for some time—in an assumption it may get requested. A special background goroutine called "scavenger" marks complete freed pages as "not needed" (using the `madvise(2)` call on Linux and similar means on other platforms) so that the OS can request those pages when it needs them. It means that monitoring RSS of a running Go process is not exactly futile but it's rather pointless w/o also monitoring the GC stats of the process itself.